# Removing the top borders and edges of the Bootstrap table

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-table

React code:

```
<div style={{paddingLeft: '8px', paddingRight: '8px'}}>
                            <div className="-subtitle">
                                <div className="pull-right" style={{marginBottom:'5px'}}>
                                    <Button bsStyle="primary" bsSize="xsmall" onClick={this.actionAdd}>Create New Parameter</Button>
                                </div>
                                <BootstrapTable
                                    data={item.params}
                                    className="removeTop"
                                    striped
                                    hover>
                                    <TableHeaderColumn
                                        className="tableHeader"
                                        width="100px"

                                    >Name</TableHeaderColumn>
                                    <TableHeaderColumn
                                        className="tableHeader"
                                        dataSort
                                        width="200px"
                                    >GUI Name</TableHeaderColumn>
                                    <TableHeaderColumn
                                        className="tableHeader"
                                        dataSort
                                        width="100px"
                                    >Default</TableHeaderColumn>
                                    <TableHeaderColumn
                                        className="tableHeader"
                                        dataSort
                                        width="300px"
                                    >Options</TableHeaderColumn>
                                    <TableHeaderColumn
                                        className="tableHeader"
                                        dataField="required"
                                        dataSort
                                        width="100px"
                                    >Required</TableHeaderColumn>
                                    <TableHeaderColumn
                                        className="tableHeader"
                                        dataField="multiline"
                                        isKey
                                        dataSort
                                        width="100px"
                                    >Multiline</TableHeaderColumn>
                                    <TableHeaderColumn
                                        className="tableHeader"
                                        dataField=""
                                        dataSort
                                        width="100px"
                                    >Delete</TableHeaderColumn>
                                </BootstrapTable>
```

I'm not sure if this is a `BootstrapTable` bug, but when there is a `pull-right` element the table creates borders around the element that has `pull-right`, which is right before the `<BootstrapTable>`. The above code gives this:
[image: Table]
When there is no `pull-right`, there is no *top* border around the `Button` which is exactly I'd like it to be (but the `Button` should be on the right side).

When I inspect with tools, it shows `.react-bs-table-container` creates borders around both `Button` and `BootstrapTable`.

But when i do add this element:

```
.react-bs-table {
        border-top: none !important;
    }
```

it only removes the top border, but not *edges*:
[image]

Is there a way to remove the borders that surround the `<Button>` ?

Answer (score 0):

Hm to remove side borders you should add

```
   .react-bs-table {
            border-top: none !important;
            border-left: none !important;
            border-right: none !important;

        }
```

And to remove the border on button you would probably need something like this:

```
button { padding: 0; border: none; background: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
border: none;
border: 0;
border-color: transparent;
outline:0;
border-collapse:collapse; (for main div)